# How would I mix up C++ with VALA

Tags: c++, vala

I need to write GUI applications for cross platform in C++ but since most of GUI libraries for C++ are bit tedious and I am quite familiar with C#/.NET I found out code Vala codes with GTK is quite interesting and bit easy compare with other ways.so how would I mix up VAlA with C++. I meant use VALA for front end and code rest of parts in C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vala GUI and logic in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885242/vala-gui-and-logic-in-c)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use QT if it's meeting your requirements. Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework with APIs for C++ programming as well.
       http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can call vala-generated code from C++, but it's plain C and quite pain to use from C++.
2. Vala can only call C code, so you'd have to wrap all your C++ code in `extern "C"` one.
3. Using Gtk from C++ via Gtkmm is no harder than using it from Vala and Qt is not any harder either.
4. Qt is the only really cross-platform option. Gtk now works natively on MacOS X, but is still not as stable. And Qt also works on most smart-phone platforms, Gtk does not.
5. Vala is not that much like C# and has it's share of quriks.

In general I'd recommend using Qt instead.

Comment: what about wxwidget? what would u think about it?

Comment: @Gryphes: I never used it, but from what I saw, wxWidget design is inspired by MFC design, which is horrible and obsolete. It's not hard to use, but lacks flexibility.

Comment: @Gryphes: Besides, wxWidget does not work on smart phone platforms either. Qt has ports for Android, iPhone, Windows CE and Symbian.

Comment: @jan-hudec nowadays there is a mature enough wxQt port to port wxWidgets to these devices using Qt.

Comment: This by far the better answer. Actually answers the question THEN suggests an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Vala compiles to C making heavy use of the GObject type system. You can use this using glibmm which is part of [gtkmm](http://gtkmm.org) from C++. But you might just as well just use gtkmm (i.e. with GtkBuilder) then …

Answer (score 0):

It may not answer your question fully, but if you use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to embed C# into c++, you can use [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) directly from windows (and it will compile and run in mac and linux too).

Then, you will be able to use C#/GTK# for the front end and code rest of parts in c++.

Comment: thanks but I am not looking for an alternative solution. I really need to make this work or at least avoid Microsoft technologies for opensource/free apps. :P